# Conditional parameter types depending on an argument

Tags: typescript

This one is tricky to explain but I have some code that runs various checks on data. There are a lot of different check types, and depending on the check type there are different types of user specified parameters.

Below is a simplified example of what I have but unfortunately the type checking is severely lacking (as shown).

For the below example consider there are three different types of checks, humidity, temp, and version, and for each check the user would specify some parameters. I'd like this parameters to be type checked:

```
export const CheckTypesArray = ['invalid-humidity', 'high-temperature', 'bad-version'] as const;
export type CheckTypes = typeof CheckTypesArray[number];

const CheckFactory: Record<CheckTypes, (data: any, parameters: any) => boolean> = {
  'high-temperature': (data: any, parameters: { threshold: number }) => {
    return data.temp > parameters.threshold;
  },
  'invalid-humidity': (data: any, parameters: { bounds: [number, number] }) => {
    return data.humidty < parameters.bounds[0] || data.humidty > parameters.bounds[1];
  },
  'bad-version': (data: any, parameters: { badVersion: string }) => {
    return data.version === parameters.badVersion;
  },
};

// example
const sampleData = {
  temp: 80,
  humidity: 105,
  version: 'v1.05',
};

// would like type checking on parameters arg here, as you can see I can pass anything in
const highTemp = CheckFactory['high-temperature'](sampleData, { anything: 100 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly noting that the type of `CheckFactory` should be

```
Record<CheckTypes, (data: any, parameters: any) => boolean
```

so TypeScript takes you at your word and only checks that references to CheckFactory follow that signature. But that's not actually what you want - you want only particular types of parameters for different types of data.

Simply omit the inaccurate typing for `CheckFactory`, and TypeScript will infer it properly.

```
const CheckFactory = {
```

With that, using, for example

```
const highTemp = CheckFactory['high-temperature'](sampleData, { anything: 100 });
```

results in the error

> Argument of type '{ anything: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ threshold: number; }'.

---

If you like using TypeScript, I'd also recommend always avoiding `any` - it's so permissive, it's as if there was no type-checking at all. If there's something whose type you don't know, `unknown` is much safer. (`unknown` is: "Could be anything." `any` is: "Could be anything, and ignore TypeScript warnings that result from its use")

Comment: cool, that works great. only issue is with that change I no longer guarantee that CheckFactory includes all the CheckTypes, so if I add something to CheckTypesArray the compiler doesn't care that CheckFactory doesn't include it. I am guessing that's not an easy fix and this whole pattern I am taking isn't correct